# Making the set of line integrals bounded.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $$P=\big\lbrace(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R} \,\,|\,\, 0\leq z\leq 1, 1\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\big\rbrace~.$$ For $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ consider the vector field $$F_{\lambda}(x,y,z) = (2x+\lambda y, -\lambda x+2y,2z)$$ in $P$. For which of $\lambda$ is the set of line integrals $$\left\{\int_{\gamma}F_{\lambda}\cdot ds \,\,|\,\,\gamma:[0,1]\to P \text{ is } C^1\right\}\in\mathbb{R}$$ bounded above?

For this question, I found out that $F$ is a gradient of a scalar function if and only if $\lambda=0$. And when $\lambda=0$, the set is certainly bounded. However, if $\lambda\neq 0$, I can set $\gamma$ as the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ winding in the appropriate direction arbitrarily many times. Then, the given set is not bounded. Therefore the answer is that $\lambda=0$.

Is my argument correct? Could anyone give me a feedback?

Comment: The argument is correct, but i am not sure about $\int_{\gamma}F_{\lambda}\cdot ds \neq 0$, if that affirmation is correct, then yes

Comment: Set $\gamma(t)=(cos(2\pi nt), sin(2\pi nt))$ for any nonzero integer $n$. Then the line integral is evaluated to be $-2\pi n\lambda$, according to my calculations. However, I frequently make mistakes (even after several times of checking.......) so hope anyone else may check as well.

Comment: You have all the reason, [Value of the integral](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/2%5Cpi%20%20n%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cleft(-%5Cleft(2cos%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)%2B%5Clambda%20%20sin%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Ccdot%20%20sin%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)%20%2B%20%5Cleft(2sin%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)-%5Clambda%20%20cos%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Ccdot%20%20cos%5Cleft(2%5Cpi%20%20nt%5Cright)%5Cright)dt%20)

Comment: Wow....thank you for the linking